# How to Deploy Flask ML model in Google cloud

Tags: python, flask, keras, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I have built three ML keras models for image classification and implement their weights in a Flask application for a comparative analysis about the testing accuracies. It works perfectly with the Flask server in the localhost.
Now I want to deploy this Flask app so it would be accessible anywhere for testing with new data.
I am new to cloud platform. Can you just guide me how to deploy this Flask app.
I have watched tutorials but Im not getting any relevant one about models weight above 700Mb. It would be great if u could help me to deploy this in Google Cloud.

Comment: In which product are you interested?

Do you need a GPU?

https://cloud.google.com/products/compute

Comment: I just want to deploy my app. A CPU is good for this model because it is testing my data and not training.

Comment: your model is on a 700MB single file?
or what is the largest file on your app?

This is because App Engine not support files larger than 35MB

Comment: Actually my three models, in total are 700Mb. I want to use them as instance in my web app. Thank you though. I found watson machine learning repository to deploy my model there.

Comment: Captain Swagger, can you post your finding as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, so I used DevOps platform in IBM cloud, where I just modified an existing server side flask Hello World web app. To use my models as instance for the image recognition process, Watson Machine Learning provides an instance which facilitates the implementation process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AI Platform within Google Cloud, is a service for develop, analyze or deploy customize models and implement it as a service.

This is the link. https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform?hl=es-419

Answer (score 0):

I think that Compute engine (GCE) is the GCP product that matches with you use case,in compute engine you can upload your flask application.

Compute engine is technically  a VM on the cloud, you can install an uninstall packages or SW without any limitation.

In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/python/tutorials/getting-started-on-compute-engine) you can find information about how to deploy a python web application on GCE.